# VisualSVN / TortoiseSVN Files not showing the update

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn, svn-checkout

I'm going to try to explain as briefly as possible what is happening:

- I have a project in `folder A`
- I add `folder A` to a repository
- Rename `A` to `A2`
- Checkout repository

Now here comes the tricky part: the website used to run on what is now `A2`, but after creating the repository and doing the checkout, the changes done in `A` aren't visible in the website *unless I save the same file in `A2`*.

As an example: let's say in the folder `A` (the repository one) I add a line of code `"Hello World"`. This doesn't show on the website unless I save the same file on folder `A2` (on the webserver) and only then this is when I see the changes made in the file in `folder A`.

This is a very strange behaviour since the site runs in what is `folder A` now. Any idea why this is happening? Thanks in advance.

(Well I forgot to mention, I'm obviously committing after changing the files in `A`).

Comment: Rewrite questions in Subversion's terms and actions, show **log of commands** and explain your business-task *clearly*!

Comment: Yeah my bad,sorry that was poorly formatted,anyway,apparently it had to do with the IIS pointing somehow to the old folder when it came to "updating" the changes. A restart of our server solved this.